# Substitute ints into Dataflow via Cloudbuild yaml

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-build

I've got a streaming Dataflow pipeline, written in Java with BEAM 2.35. It commits data to BigQuery via StorageWriteApi. Initially the code looks like

```
BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
  .withTimePartitioning(/* some column */)
  .withClustering(/* another column */)
  .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STORAGE_WRITE_API)
  .withTriggeringFrequency(Duration.standardSeconds(30))
  .withNumStorageWriteApiStreams(20) // want to make this dynamic
```

This code runs in different environment eg Dev & Prod. When I deploy in Dev I want 2 StorageWriteApiStreams, in Prod I want 20, and I'm trying to pass/resolve these values at the moment I deploy with a Cloudbuild.

The cloudbuild-dev.yaml looks like

```
steps:
  - lots-of-steps
args:
 --numStorageWriteApiStreams=${_NUM_STORAGEWRITEAPI_STREAMS}
substitutions:
  _PROJECT: dev-project
  _NUM_STORAGEWRITEAPI_STREAMS: '2'
```

I expose the substitution in the job code with an interface

```
  ValueProvider<String> getNumStorageWriteApiStreams();
  void setNumStorageWriteApiStreams(ValueProvider<String> numStorageWriteApiStreams);
```

I then refactor the writeTableRows() call to invoke getNumStorageWriteApiStreams()

```
BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
  .withTimePartitioning(/* some column */)
  .withClustering(/* another column */)
  .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STORAGE_WRITE_API)
  .withTriggeringFrequency(Duration.standardSeconds(30))
  .withNumStorageWriteApiStreams(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(options.getNumStorageWriteApiStreams())))
```

Now it's dynamic but I get a build failure on account of `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: methods with same signature getNumStorageWriteApiStreams() but incompatible return types: [class java.lang.Integer, interface org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider]`

My understanding was that `Integer.parseInt` returns an `int`, which I want so I can pass it to `withNumStorageWriteApiStreams()` which requires an `int`.

I'd appreciate any help I can get here thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `BigQueryOptions.java` already has a method `getNumStorageWriteApiStreams()` that returns an Integer. I was unknowingly trying to rewrite it with a different return, oops.

https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryOptions.java#L95-L98